# Construct a Type from the types in the value of another Type

Tags: typescript

Given I have the following type:

```
export type CommandsTypes = {
  "command1": {
    propA: string;
    propB: number;
  };

  "command2": {
    propC: string;
    propD: number;
  };
};
```

I want to construct an object in a typesafe way such that:

```
const myCommand: Command<"command1"> = {
  type: "command1",
  payload: {
    propA: "abc",
    probB: 123
  }
}
```

My thinking is something like:

```
export type Command<K extends keyof CommandsTypes> = {
  type: K;
  payload: { [P in CommandsTypes[K]]: any };
};
```

But TS doesnt seem to like that.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a mapped type you need the keys of `CommandsTypes[K]`. A solution that uses a mapped type and preserves the property types would be :

```
export type Command<K extends keyof CommandsTypes> = {
    type: K;
    payload: { [P in keyof CommandsTypes[K]]: CommandsTypes[K][P] };
};
```

But you don't really need a mapped type, this would create the same type:

```
export type Command<K extends keyof CommandsTypes> = {
   type: K;
   payload: CommandsTypes[K]
```